# Как правильно сформировать таблицу и связи в БД?

Tags: mysql, laravel

Попалась очень сложная задача. Помогите пожалуйста.

Есть роль `(user)`, есть категории `(bank, private, work)`, есть права чтение/запись `(read/edit)`. Как правильно оформить таблицы в БД и как правильно оформить связи. Как я себе это представляю на данный момент:

**Role:**
*id: 1

title: user*

**Category:**
*id: 1

title: bank

id: 2

title: private

id: 3

title: work*

**readEdit**
*id: 1

title: read

id: 2

title: edit*

Что нужно в целом, если у пользователя стоит галочка `read` и `edit` на против категории `private`, то все записи этой категории он может видеть и редактировать, а если только `read` то только видеть.

Подскажите, может кто сталкивался с таким, может где похожее есть. Буду рад любой помощи, спасибо.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: *если у пользователя стоит галочка read и edit на против категории ..., то все записи этой категории он может видеть и редактировать, а если только read то только видеть.* А допустима ли ситуация, когда edit установлена, а read нет? ответ неочевиден - ведь теоретически никто не запрещает устанавливать значения "вслепую"...

Comment: @Akina Да есть это проблема, буду думать как и ее решить. Я думаю если Read не будет стоять то Edit будет затемнена

Comment: Имхо разумнее при установлении edit автоматом устанавливать read, а при сбросе read автоматом сбрасывать edit. Или сменить два чекбокса на три радиобатона - none, read, edit.

Answer (score 0):

В терминах MySQL:

```sql
CREATE TABLE privileges ( user_id BIGINT NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY user (user_id),
                          category ENUM('bank', 'private', 'work') NOT NULL,
                          UNIQUE (user_id, category),
                          access_mask SET('read', 'edit') NOT NULL DEFAULT '');
```

Если список категорий динамический, то вместо поля ENUM будет поле-FK в таблицу категорий.

Если ситуация, когда edit установлено, а read нет - недопустима, то

```
access_mask SET('read', 'edit') NOT NULL DEFAULT '' CHECK (access_mask != 'edit')
```